# Php rearrange array according to the key

Tags: php

I tried convert the array type from $data to $data2 but didn't have success.

In the `$data` array all values placed according to dates.

But in the `$data2` values are placed according to the title.

I wonder if it's convertable array.

```
$data['Group1']['Date1']['Empty'] = 5;
$data['Group1']['Date1']['Reservated'] = 1;
$data['Group1']['Date1']['WillReturn'] = 3;
$data['Group1']['Date1']['Remains'] = 1;
$data['Group1']['Date2']['Empty'] = 2;
$data['Group1']['Date2']['Reservated'] = 2;
$data['Group1']['Date2']['WillReturn'] = 3;
$data['Group1']['Date2']['Remains'] = -3;

$data['Group2']['Date1']['Empty'] = 0;
$data['Group2']['Date1']['Reservated'] = 1;
$data['Group2']['Date1']['WillReturn'] = 3;
$data['Group2']['Date1']['Remains'] = -4;
$data['Group2']['Date2']['Empty'] = 10;
$data['Group2']['Date2']['Reservated'] = 1;
$data['Group2']['Date2']['WillReturn'] = 1;
$data['Group2']['Date2']['Remains'] = 8;

$data2 = [
    'Group1' => [
        [ 'Title' => 'Empty',
            'Date1' => 5,
            'Date2' => 2,

        ],
        [ 'Title' => 'Reservated',
            'Date1' => 1,
            'Date2' => 2,

        ],
        [ 'Title' => 'WillReturn',
            'Date1' => 3,
            'Date2' => 3,
        ],
        [ 'Title' => 'Remains',
            'Date1' => 1,
            'Date2' => -3,
        ],
        // etc...
    ],
    'Group2' => [
        [ 'Title' => 'Empty',
            'Date1' => 0,
            'Date2' => 10,

        ],
        [ 'Title' => 'Reservated',
            'Date1' => 1,
            'Date2' => 1,

        ],
        [ 'Title' => 'WillReturn',
            'Date1' => 3,
            'Date2' => 1,
        ],
        [ 'Title' => 'Remains',
            'Date1' => -4,
            'Date2' => -8,
        ],
        // etc...
    ],
    // etc...
];
```

Some try here:

```
$new = [];
    $grp = array_keys($datax);
    $i =0;
    foreach($datax as $key => $val)
    {
        $dates = array_keys($val);
        foreach($val as $k=>$v)
        {
            $cases = array_keys($v);
            $caseAndVals[$i]=$v;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    $z =0;
    $y = 0;
    foreach($grp as $g)
    {
        foreach($cases as $c)
        {
            $new[$g][$z]['Title']=$c;
            foreach($dates as $d)
            {
                $new[$g][$z][$d] = 'values which correspond to the date and title';
            }
            $z++;
        }

    }
```

I converted array according to group and cases but i didn't have success to  place values corresponded dates...

Comment: @Barmar there is no real code really. I'm just thinking of it. If you search my topics you will see that i'm not here for free coding service.

Comment: You wrote "I tried ... but didn't have success.". Show what you tried.

Comment: Ah.. allright.. I'll paste here in a hour

Comment: @Barmar sorry for late. I placed here my try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.

To get the `values which correspond to the date and title`, use `$data[$g][$d][$c]`.

And you need to reset `$z` to `0` each time through the `$grp` loop, so you get correct indexes on each group array.

```
$new = array();
$grp = array_keys($data);

foreach($data as $key => $val)
{
    $dates = array_keys($val);
    foreach($val as $k=>$v)
    {
        $cases = array_keys($v);
        $caseAndVals[]=$v;
    }
}

foreach($grp as $g)
{
    $z = 0;
    foreach($cases as $c)
    {
        $new[$g][$z]['Title']=$c;
        foreach($dates as $d)
        {
            $new[$g][$z][$d] = $data[$g][$d][$c];
        }
        $z++;
    }
}
```